# Google ID Token verification fails in PHP, but works with tokeninfo endpoint

Tags: php, google-api, jwt, google-api-php-client, verification

I'm encountering an issue verifying a Google ID token using the PHP API. The `tokeninfo` endpoint successfully verifies it, but `$client->verifyIdToken($id_token)` returns false in my PHP code. I have also downgraded my PHP version to 7.4

## Questions:

1. Has anyone else faced this issue with PHP 7.4?
2. Are there known compatibility issues with specific library versions?
3. Are there additional troubleshooting steps I can try?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

## Here's an the code I am using:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
      
// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$CLIENT_ID = 'token-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx-000.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$id_token = $_POST['credential'];
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token); //Not working

echo file_get_contents('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token='.$id_token); //Works

echo var_dump($payload); //false

if ($payload) {
  //$userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
   //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
?>
```

## Steps taken:

- Verified client ID is correct.
- Checked for error messages or exceptions.
- Inspected the $payload variable after verification.
- Verified network traffic to Google's servers.

Comment: You need two tokens .. Of which I don't see here ..  You need the "main" token, and then a "access" token that needs refreshed every so often because they expire ..  Your code doesn't look like the native PHP Oath provided by Google [HERE](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) -- If that package is correct, you need to read the documentation thouroughly.

Comment: But that is the code i found on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Comment: Because Google is KNOWN for their accurate documentation ..

Comment: Use the API I linked .. It's pretty easy to use, and there is plenty of docs and Stack Overflow help